# Python Chiptunes with PWM

Tags: python, audio, pwm

I'm building a super barebones game console with a rasPi zero. I'm trying to get it to play some rudimentary music - I'd like to be able to write little tunes programatically (eventually have the games generate the music perhaps).

I have connected a little piezo buzzer to PWM pin 12 and can make it play some notes with this little python program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(12, 100)

c4 = 261
d4 = 294
e4 = 329
f4 = 349
g4 = 392
a4 = 440
b4 = 493
c5 = 523.25

speed = 0.1

GPIO.output(12, True) 
p.start(10) # 10% duty cycle sounds 'ok'

p.ChangeFrequency(c4)
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(d4)  
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(e4)   
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(f4)  
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(g4)    
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(a4)    
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(b4)    
time.sleep(speed)
p.ChangeFrequency(c5)    
time.sleep(speed)

p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

which definitely gives me a starting point, however, I'd really like to be able to have more than 1 voice - maybe 4: enough for a simple drum beat and bass line.

I'm at a loss as to how to combine multiple 'instruments' with this set up.

[I did some research](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszjm2/projects/other/Arduino_music_using_Direct_Digital_Synthesis.html) which enabled me to write a program that attempts to do some wavetable synthesis but all I got was a very high pitched modem squeak (I converted the article's sine wave data into duty cycle percentages):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) 
p = GPIO.PWM(12, 100)

c4 = 261

wave = [
    50.20, 51.37, 52.55, 53.73, 54.90, 56.08, 57.25, 58.43, 
    59.61, 60.78, 61.96, 63.14, 64.31, 65.49, 66.67, 67.84, 
    69.02, 70.20, 71.37, 72.55, 73.33, 74.51, 75.69, 76.47, 
    77.65, 78.82, 79.61, 80.78, 81.57, 82.35, 83.53, 84.31, 
    85.10, 85.88, 87.06, 87.84, 88.63, 89.41, 90.20, 90.59, 
    91.37, 92.16, 92.55, 93.33, 94.12, 94.51, 94.90, 95.69, 
    96.08, 96.47, 96.86, 97.25, 97.65, 98.04, 98.43, 98.43, 
    98.82, 99.22, 99.22, 99.61, 99.61, 99.61, 99.61, 99.61, 
    100.00, 99.61, 99.61, 99.61, 99.61, 99.61, 99.22, 99.22, 
    98.82, 98.43, 98.43, 98.04, 97.65, 97.25, 96.86, 96.47, 
    96.08, 95.69, 94.90, 94.51, 94.12, 93.33, 92.55, 92.16, 
    91.37, 90.59, 90.20, 89.41, 88.63, 87.84, 87.06, 85.88, 
    85.10, 84.31, 83.53, 82.35, 81.57, 80.78, 79.61, 78.82, 
    77.65, 76.47, 75.69, 74.51, 73.33, 72.55, 71.37, 70.20, 
    69.02, 67.84, 66.67, 65.49, 64.31, 63.14, 61.96, 60.78, 
    59.61, 58.43, 57.25, 56.08, 54.90, 53.73, 52.55, 51.37, 
    50.20, 49.02, 47.84, 46.67, 45.49, 44.31, 43.14, 41.96, 
    40.78, 39.61, 38.43, 37.25, 36.08, 34.90, 33.73, 32.55, 
    31.37, 30.20, 29.02, 27.84, 27.06, 25.88, 24.71, 23.92, 
    22.75, 21.57, 20.78, 19.61, 18.82, 18.04, 16.86, 16.08, 
    15.29, 14.51, 13.33, 12.55, 11.76, 10.98, 10.20, 9.80, 
    9.02, 8.24, 7.84, 7.06, 6.27, 5.88, 5.49, 4.71, 4.31, 
    3.92, 3.53, 3.14, 2.75, 2.35, 1.96, 1.96, 1.57, 1.18, 
    1.18, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 0.39, 0.78, 0.78, 
    0.78, 0.78, 0.78, 1.18, 1.18, 1.57, 1.96, 1.96, 2.35, 
    2.75, 3.14, 3.53, 3.92, 4.31, 4.71, 5.49, 5.88, 6.27, 
    7.06, 7.84, 8.24, 9.02, 9.80, 10.20, 10.98, 11.76, 
    12.55, 13.33, 14.51, 15.29, 16.08, 16.86, 18.04, 18.82, 
    19.61, 20.78, 21.57, 22.75, 23.92, 24.71, 25.88, 27.06, 
    27.84, 29.02, 30.20, 31.37, 32.55, 33.73, 34.90, 36.08, 
    37.25, 38.43, 39.61, 40.78, 41.96, 43.14, 44.31, 45.49, 
    46.67, 47.84, 49.02, ]
freq = len(wave)

GPIO.output(12, True)
p.start(0)
p.ChangeFrequency(16000)
try:
    while True:
      for value in wave:
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(value)
        time.sleep(1/(c4*freq))

except:
  p.stop()
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

I'm well beyond my ability with regards to sound theory, but I guess this is as good a place to start as any. I've found a lot of arduino based resources which all appear to use various timers which pushes my limited understanding of C makes it harder to translate them into *rasperrypython*. I really do only want very simple tunes (and maybe the odd sound effect?).

How can I use python to generate 4-voice chip tunes over PWM?

UPDATE: so I found [an article](https://makezine.com/projects/make-35/advanced-arduino-sound-synthesis/) that explains the whole wavetable thing a little clearer (for my brain anyway), so I guess my question becomes - how do I control the PWM and update the duty cycle with enough precision using python?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can I generate 4-voice chip tunes with python and PWM?

Comment: One of the problems you are running in to is trying to do real-time hardware control on a non-real-time system.

Comment: Yeah, it's frustrating because obviously the Raspberry Pi is fully capable of outputting audio, it just seems to be really difficult to do it from Python. I could probably knock up what I want with an ATTiny, I just really don't want to do the rest of my project in C.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have simply can't work.

1. There is no way RPi.GPIO or Python can reliably software time PWM at a frequency of 16000Hz.  That means the process must reliably re-schedule every 32µs.
2. There is no way Python can reliably do a time.sleep(1/(c4*freq)).  Where c4=261, freq=256, c4*freq=66816, so that is asking for a 15µs sleep.

Problem 1 is surmountable (but not with RPi.GPIO), you could use hardware timed PWM.

I don't see a solution for problem 2 unless you have a supercomputer to spare.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second code block is wrong anyway - I don't completely understand how to do the equivalent in python.